# adjusting python autoviv to take "+=1" increments

Tags: python, autovivification

I am using some common python autovivification code build dictionaries:

```
class autoviv(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""

    def __getitem__(self, item):  
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:     
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

One thing I'd love to be able to is to increment values in the case where no key currently exists at the specified dictionary nesting level, using += notation like so:

```
d['a']+=1
```

Doing so will return the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'autoviv' and 'int'
```

To get around this I've built a step that checks whether the key exists before incrementing it, but I'd love to do away with that step if I could.

How should I modify the above autoviv() code to get this enhancement?  I've googled and tried different approaches for a few hours but no joy.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What does `d["a"]` return?

Comment: Oh sorry. The way the autoviv above works as-is: the minimum input would be "d['a']=X (e.g. 1)".  If "d['a']" doesn't exist yet, it will create that key in the dict and set its value = the number you specify like {a:1}.  Only if the key already exists, THEN you can use "d['a']+=1".  Right now, if the key doesn't exist and you use +=1 you'll throw an error.  What I'd like to be able to do is, for a non-existent key, use  "d['a']+=1" and have the k:v pair be auto-created without throwing an error.  Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Autovivication is already in Python, inside of `collections`' `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict


#Let's say we want to count every character
#  that occurs
text = "Let's implement autovivication!"
di = defaultdict(int)
for char in text:
    di[char] += 1
print(di)

#Another way of doing this is using a defualt string
#  (or default int, or whatever you want)
currentDict = {'bob':'password','mike':'12345'}
di = defaultdict(lambda:'unknown user', currentDict)
print(di['bob'])
print(di['sheryl'])
```

However, if you're trying to implement your own.  You should assign your item and then get the reference to it.

```
def __getitem__(self, item):  
    try:
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
    except KeyError:
        value = self[item] = type(self)()        
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
```

Comment: Thanks!  However: `from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(int)
d['a']['v']+=1` gives me "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"